EF Core Entity Configuration WithMany and Where
Is there a way in the IEntityTypeConfiguration to add a where clause to the collection. As a simple (incomplete) example, I would like the Form.Items to only include the FormItems which have the FormId equal to the Form and ParentFormItemId equal to null.
public class Form
{
    public Guid FormId { get; set; }
    public List<FormItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class FormItem
{
    public Guid FormItemId { get; set; }
    public Guid FormId { get; set; }
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentFormItemId { get; set; }
    public List<FormItem> Children { get; set; }
}

public class FormConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Form>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Form> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(u => u.FormId);

        builder
            .HasMany(x => x.Items)
            .WithOne(c => c.Form);
    }
}

so essentially is there a way to do something like
builder
    .HasMany(x => x.Items)
    .WithOne(c => c.Form)
    .Where(x => x.ParentFormId == null);

Form.Items would then only include the parent FormItems linked to that form, rather all the items linked to that form.
Thanks

The configuration only defines a static relationship that's a reflection of the database structure. It's up to you whether and how you actually navigate the relationships. For example, you can use filtered includes.

As we are using UseLazyLoadingProxies on the DBContext, the "include" is automatic when accessing that property. nHibernate allows you to control the "where" on that proxy, so was hoping there was similar functionality in EF. Thanks. I will just create a separate property for just the root children.
